# jquery autocomplete NOT calling "source".php

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete using a php page as the data source. I tried it in Safari 5.1.9, Caminio 2.1.2, and Stainless 0.8 (all on Mac). Autocomplete does NOT work!!!

Please help!

I have researched this and seen many similar problems but no solutions. I do not know if it is HTML 5 or what...

I followed the example from here: http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/

I am using jquery 1.8.3 and jquery-ui 1.9.2 because jquery 1.9+ breaks a major component of the web site.

Here is my code for the index (index.php) page:

```
<?php require_once "connectToDatabase.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - PHP Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $('#abbrev').val("");

    $("#state").autocomplete({
        source: "states.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
            $('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);
        } //function(event, ui)
    }); //$("#state").autocomplete

    $("#state_abbrev").autocomplete({
        source: "states_abbrev.php",
        minLength: 2
    }); //("#state_abbrev").autocomplete

}); //function

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">   
<div class="hero-unit">
<h1>jQuery UI Autocomplete</h1>
<p>This example will use US states and territories to populate the autocomplete. It will also demonstrate how to fill other fields with data returned from the database. This data can be used to fill a visible text box or a hidden form field. It also demonstrates the basic autocomplete functionality which may be fine for some applications.</p>
<h2>Start typing the name of a state or territory of the United States</h2>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="autocompleteForm" name="autocompleteForm" action=""  method="post">
<fieldset>

<div class="control-group">
<label for="state">State (abbreviation in separate field): </label>
<div class="controls">  
<input type="text" id="state"  name="state" /> <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="abbrev" name="abbrev" maxlength="2" size="2"/>
<input type="hidden" id="state_id" name="state_id" />
<input type="hidden" id="form_submitted" name="form_submitted" value="true" />

</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<label for="state_abbrev">State (replaced with abbreviation): </label>
<div class="controls">  
<input type="text" id="state_abbrev" name="state_abbrev" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" />
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>

</div>

    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo "<p>";
    while (list($key,$value) = each($_POST)){
    echo "<strong>" . $key . "</strong> = ".$value."<br />";
    }
echo "</p>";
}
?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code for the first php source page (states.php):

```
<?php require_once "connectToDatabase.php"; ?>

<script>
function notSet(){
        var answer = confirm('NOT SET');
} 
function set(){
        var answer = confirm('IS SET');
}
</script>

<?php

if ( !isset($_GET['term']) ){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
    , 'notSet();'
    , '</script>';
    exit;
} //if

echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'notSet();'
   , '</script>';

try {
    $conn = connectionFunction();
} //try
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} //catch

$return_arr = array();

if ($conn){
    //$ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $ac_term = $_GET['term']."%";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM states where state like :term";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->execute();

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['value'] = $row['state'];
        $row_array['abbrev'] = $row['abbrev'];
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    } //while
} //if
/* Free connection resources. */
$conn = null; 
/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

Here is my code for the first php source page (states.php):

```
<?php require_once "connectToDatabase.php"; ?>

<script>
function notSet(){
        var answer = confirm('NOT SET');
} 
function set(){
        var answer = confirm('IS SET');
}
</script>

<?php

if ( !isset($_GET['term']) ){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
    , 'notSet();'
    , '</script>';
    exit;
} //if

echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'notSet();'
   , '</script>';

try {
    $conn = connectionFunction();
} //try
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} //catch

$return_arr = array();

if ($conn){
    //$ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $ac_term = $_GET['term']."%";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM states where state like :term";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->execute();

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['label'] = $row['state'];
        $row_array['value'] = $row['abbrev'];
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    } //while
} //if
/* Free connection resources. */
$conn = null; 
/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

Here is the MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `states` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `state` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `abbrev` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(1, 'Alabama', 'AL');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(2, 'Alaska', 'AK');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(3, 'Arizona', 'AZ');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(4, 'Arkansas', 'AR');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(5, 'California', 'CA');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(6, 'Colorado', 'CO');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(7, 'Connecticut', 'CT');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(8, 'Delaware', 'DE');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(9, 'Florida', 'FL');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(10, 'Georgia', 'GA');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(11, 'Hawaii', 'HI');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(12, 'Idaho', 'ID');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(13, 'Illinois', 'IL');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(14, 'Indiana', 'IN');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(15, 'Iowa', 'IA');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(16, 'Kansas', 'KS');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(17, 'Kentucky', 'KY');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(18, 'Louisiana', 'LA');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(19, 'Maine', 'ME');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(20, 'Maryland', 'MD');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(21, 'Massachusetts', 'MA');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(22, 'Michigan', 'MI');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(23, 'Minnesota', 'MN');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(24, 'Mississippi', 'MS');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(25, 'Missouri', 'MO');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(26, 'Montana', 'MT');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(27, 'Nebraska', 'NE');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(28, 'Nevada', 'NV');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(29, 'New Hampshire', 'NH');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(30, 'New Jersey', 'NJ');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(31, 'New Mexico', 'NM');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(32, 'New York', 'NY');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(33, 'North Carolina', 'NC');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(34, 'North Dakota', 'ND');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(35, 'Ohio', 'OH');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(36, 'Oklahoma', 'OK');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(37, 'Oregon', 'OR');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(38, 'Pennsylvania', 'PA');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(39, 'Rhode Island', 'RI');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(40, 'South Carolina', 'SC');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(41, 'South Dakota', 'SD');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(42, 'Tennessee', 'TN');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(43, 'Texas', 'TX');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(44, 'Utah', 'UT');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(45, 'Vermont', 'VT');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(46, 'Virginia', 'VA');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(47, 'Washington', 'WA');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(48, 'West Virginia', 'WV');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(49, 'Wisconsin', 'WI');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(50, 'Wyoming', 'WY');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(51, 'American Samoa', 'AS');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(52, 'District of Columbia', 'DC');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(53, 'Federated States of ', 'FM');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(54, 'Guam', 'GU');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(55, 'Marshall Islands', 'MH');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(56, 'Northern Mariana Isl', 'MP');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(57, 'Palau', 'PW');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(58, 'Puerto Rico', 'PR');
INSERT INTO `states` VALUES(59, 'Virgin Islands', 'VI');
```

Note that in the php source pages I have JS alerts, that is so that I can see if the pages are working when I call their URL directly.

In my trouble shooting I figured I would try a working example, and it did not work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the php files have to return proper javascript arrays are the result....

Comment: @ArunPJohny When I open [states_abbrev.php?term=penn](http://states_abbrev.php?term=penn) I get the array json encoded `[{"label":"Pennsylvania","value":"PA"}]`. So the php files **ARE** returning the correct results

Answer (score 0):

Check the browser console and see if an error exception has been returned. Is the array returned rightly? Also, try to open the states.php file and see if the array encoded to json is returned without any error.

Comment: No errors in the console. When I open [states_abbrev.php?term=penn](http://states_abbrev.php?term=penn) I get the array json encoded `[{"label":"Pennsylvania","value":"PA"}]`. All seems to be working well. I also tried the JS packages that came with the download: `<script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<scr ipt src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>`. No luck either.

Comment: One interesting thing I found is that the code that dumps out the form values; `<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo "<p>";
    while (list($key,$value) = each($_POST)){
    echo "<strong>" . $key . "</strong> = ".$value."<br />";
    }
echo "</p>";
}
?>` is not returning anything after hitting submit. That means nothing is being passed to `$_POST['submit']`.